# Assigning values to Django template variables in javascript

Tags: python, django, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

```js
<script>
{{ somedjangovariable }}=2;
</script>
```

In a html page can we do something like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
<script>
{{ somedjangovariable }}=2;
</script>
```

in a Django template, your tag will be filled by the python **value** of `somedjangovariable`, computed server-side.

It can work, but it is quite a strange pattern to use a server-side value to name a javascript variable.